# Uncaught Error: No module: LocalStorageModule

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, local-storage

I am trying to work on an AngularJS project with Local Storage.
I am making a todo list application and storing each todo note using `angular-local-storage`.
I have made a `localStorageService` which is used in my controller. I have injected the service as a dependency in my app.js however I keep getting a blank page and a console error: `Uncaught Error: No module: LocalStorageModule`.  Is there something wrong with my syntax??... Or am I using my service incorrectly?

**app.coffee**

```
@angTut = angular.module("angTut", ['LocalStorageModule']);

@angTut.config(["$routeProvider", ($routeProvider) ->
$routerprovider = $routeProvider;
$routeProvider.when("/",
    templateUrl: "views/Pages/welcome.html"
    controller: "PagesController"
);
$routeProvider.when("/add",
    templateUrl: "views/Todos/add.html"
    controller: "TodosController"
);
$routeProvider.otherwise(
    redirectTo: "/"
);
])
```

**todo_controller.coffee**

```
"use strict"
@angTut.controller('TodosController', (
$scope
todoService
) ->
$scope.save = ->
    todoService.add($scope.note)
    $scope.list()

$scope.clear = ->
    todoService.clear()
    $scope.list()

$scope.list = ->
    $scope.notes = []
    storedNotes = todoService.get(true)
    if storedNotes?
        i = 0
        while i < storedNotes.length
          $scope.notes.push storedNotes[i]
          i++

)
```

**todo_service.coffee**

```
'use strict'
@angTut.service('todoService', (
localStorageService
) ->
addFn = (data) ->
    existingValue = getFn();
    if(existingValue isnt null)
        newData = existingValue + ',' + data
        localStorageService.add('someStorageKey', newData)
    else
        localStorageService.add('someStorageKey', data)
    return data

getFn = (returnAsArray) ->
    storedNotes = localStorageService.get('someStorageKey')
    if storedNotes? and returnAsArray
        return storedNotes.split(',')
    else
        return storedNotes

clearFn = ->
    localStorageService.clearAll()

add: addFn
get: getFn
clear: clearFn
)
```

Comment: did you refer to the angular's local storage module? it is not a part of angular though.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned it's a third party component that I installed via bower...

Comment: you have the import correctly on index.html? The name of this module is the same that one declared into the lib?

Answer (score 1):

I am certain it has to do with how you referenced the dependency in your `bower.json`. The name of this component isn't exactly as the project name on github. It's possible the bower component was recently renamed but I'm not very sure about that.
If you try searching for the component with the project name;

```
bower search angular-local-storage

No results.
```

I believe the name of the component you intend to use is 'angular-localstorage'.

```
☺  bower search angular-localstorage                                                                       ruby-2.0.0-p247
Search results:

angular-localstorage git://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.git
```

If that is the case, then make the necessary changes to make sure you're referencing it right in your 'bower.json' file.

E.g

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "angular-localstorage": "*"
}
```

Don't forget to name it right in your view as well.

Note that the actual Javascript file is still 'angular-local-storage.js'

E.g.

`<script src="components/angular-localstorage/angular-local-storage.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

not the case, the module does exist on bowel with the name

```
angular-local-storage git://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.git
```